# Problem getting html form data through Flask and Python

Tags: python, flask

```py
from flask import Flask, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])

def signup():
    email = request.form['email']
    print("Adresa de email este: " + email)
    return redirect('/')
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/signup" method = "post">
        <input type = "text" name = "email"></input>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Signup"></input>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

So I m trying to print the email that I m writing in the html form but I get the following error:
" Your file couldn’t be accessed.
It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ".

The html file is in the specific PyCharm directory, near the main.py file.

Comment: Where are you trying to reference the file inside your code?

Comment: I was thinking this has to be done but i don t know where i should place it exactly

Answer (score 0):

You `redirect('/')` after processing the POST data. But `/` is not a route that you defined in your flask app. Therefore when your browser follows that redirect I assume it shows the ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error, which is a simple 404 error page generated by it (Chrome?).

That's not an error on the Python/Flask server though. There in the stdout print you should see the email value just fine.

If you assumed to see the email in the browser instead, you should have done something like

```py
def signup():
    email = request.form['email']
    return email   # DEBUG return
```

Comment: I tried to print it on the console, not on the web page, but it still doesn't work. I tried putting the path to the html file in the redirect( ) but nada.

Comment: You don't need to out the path ,  make a new `@app.route('/')` in which you render the html file you want to show on the following route . and keep the html files in templates forlder.